Is TRUNCASE a symbol that ever existed in a Lisp implementation?
It appears that the Kate editor has a lot of xml files describing various languages, for highlighting purposes. For example, commonlisp.xml contains all 978 standard Common Lisp symbols. Other projects depends on these files, like Skylighting in Haskell and then indirectly matterhorn.
But commonlisp.xml also define a mysterious TRUNCASE function at line 901, which does not exist in the standard.
The vim editor also define this function, in runtime/syntax/lisp.vim.
I suspect the vim file to be generated from the Kate one, or inversely, or from the same source as Kate.
The above file also says:

Clisp additions courtesy of http://clisp.cvs.sourceforge.net/*checkout*/clisp/clisp/emacs/lisp.vim

We can find the file on sourceforge, but there is no mention of truncase here:
https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/emacs/lisp.vim
But maybe there is another Lisp implementation that used to define this function.
So I'm wondering if this is all just a bug that survived the passage of time and made its way into various projects, or if there is a good reason for this function to be added to the list of Lisp symbols.
Was there ever a TRUNCASE function defined as part of a Lisp dialect?

I don't think there is/was an operator or type called truncase. A google search for "truncase" and "lisp" returns nothing, besides syntax file defs. That was very likely meant to be truncate. truncase can be deleted.

Someone mistyped truncate I bet.  Really the right question is 'is there an implementation which has that symbol as something worth treating specially today?' not 'was there ever one?'.

or somebody manipulated some file for some other random reason -> where does this change originally come from?

I examined the top of several versions of the mentioned lisp.vim and all of them had truncase. I checked out linked-to CVS repo for clisp and examined lisp.vim, it did NOT have truncase.
Other nails in the coffin:

There is no TRUNCASE in the index of my copy of Common Lisp, the Language, 2nd Edition, only TRUNCATE.
It's not in ZetaLisp's index, either the 3rd or 6th edition.
It's not in the HyperSpec.
It's not in clasp.

Pretty sure it was just a typo for truncate.

Thank you for taking the time to do this

There is no mention of this symbol anywhere else and it is unlikely that it ever existed. The linked code is probably a bug and a fix was submitted and merged.
